# IOS - Update progress bar from a async call

Tags: ios, asynchronous, progress-bar, progress

I need to parse a json in the background thread. This parser also needs to update my progress bar using delegate method, but for some reason my progress bar is only updated and the end of the process. My code is the following:

```
-(void)downloadStuff
{
   // some other code
   downloaderController.delegate = self;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
       [downloaderController parseJson];
   });
}
```

The method parseJson during the process calls the delegate several times to update the progress bar like this:

```
-(void)updateProgressBar
{
      //Is anyone listening
      if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(updateProgressBar)])
      {
         [_delegate updateProgressBar];
      }
}
```

And my updateProgressBar is the following:

```
(void)updateProgressBar
{
    _progressBar.progress =+ 0.05f;
}
```

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch back to the main thread before calling `updateProgressBar`. You can use GCD or `performSelector` to do so.

```
                [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Can you give an exemple plz? I don't know what methods are you talking about.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit strange to user `performSelectorOnMainThread` inside the use of GCD. It would be more consistent to use `dispatch_async` with `dispatch_get_main_queue` instead.

Comment: But the dispatch_get_main_queue will only run after the async call end, or will it not?

Comment: No, both GCD and perform selector methods will push the request onto the main thread queue where it will be executed on the 'next' iteration of the run loop.